# Как установить ширину в jssor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

В Jssor слайдере(carousel slider) фотографии разной ширины(высота одинаковая)
Каким образом сделать так, чтобы ширина блока с фотографией была равна реальной ширине фотографии?
Опция $SlideWidth: 234 задает размер всем div'ам, которые оборачивают IMG, ее отключение не помогает.

```html
<div id="myslide" u="slides" >
    <div><img src="http://site.com/html/img/userimg/galslider/1.png" alt="" width="229" height="343" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://site.com/html/img/userimg/galslider/2.png" alt="" width="229" height="343" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://site.com/html/img/userimg/galslider/3.png" alt="" width="515" height="343" /></div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы у дивов, обёртывающих изображения, была разная ширина?

Comment: Да, чтобы дивы были такого же размера как и изображения

Answer (score 1):

В контексте предоставленной информации следующий способ должен помочь:

```
#myslide > div {
    /* Блок будет внутристрочным. По умолчанию размеры такого блока 
    вычисляются исходя из размера содержимого. */
    display: inline-block; 
    /* Сбросит значения ширины, установленные в админке. */
    width: auto !important; 
}
```

– нужо дописать в вашу таблицу стилей.

Comment: Не работает фотография переходит во всю длину, но следующий див накрывает ее:((

Comment: @AlexanderChibilyaev В контексте предоставленного вами кусочка кода всё работает. Вы работаете на локальной машине или сайт есть в сети? Если есть в сети, опубликуйте ссылку - посмотрим.

Comment: Сайт на вагранте. Если Вы есть вконтакте, можете меня добавить? https://vk.com/aachibilyaev

Comment: Работали с Дмитрием час, в итоге ни к чему не пришли(((

Comment: Увы, перелистывание слайдера задаётся с помощью JS путём изменения свойства `left`, с его же помощью вычисляются начальные позиции изображений, размеры контейнеров и размер шага для каждого перелистывания. Путём обычного изменения CSS-свойств проблему не решить. Скорее всего потребуется допиливать скрипт. Ждём тех, кто сталкивался с этой ситуацией.

Comment: Выражаю Дмитрию огромную благодарность за помощь. Впилил OWL. Если с данной задачей кто сталкивался, прошу отписать решение.